# Practical applications of eigenvalues/eigenvectors in computer science

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, applications

What are the most important/popular applications of eigenvalues and eigenvectors in practical terms, in fields such as computer science and computer graphics?

Wikipedia does mention some but doesn't really elaborate much.

Answer (score 7):

Eigenvectors and eigenvalues are important for understanding the properties of [expander graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph), which I understand to have several applications in computer science (such as derandomizing random algorithms). They also give rise to a [graph partitioning algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition#Spectral_Partitioning.2FSpectral_Bisection).

Perhaps the most famous application, however, is to Google's [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

PRuler is an iPhone app that lets you measure objects using a credit card and your iPhone camera.  I'm told it uses a Singular Value Decomposition (which is very closely related to eigenvalues and eigenvectors)